# What are the advantages of using \Umathchardef over \Umathcode with \let?

Tags: xetex, luatex

I've been playing around with unicode mathematics input. I noticed that both

```
\Umathchardef\plus = 2 0 "002B
```

and

```
\Umathcode "002B = 2 0 "002B
\let\plus=+
```

lead to the same behavior of `\plus` in math mode (assuming that a suitable math font has been assigned to family 0).

What are the advantages/disadvantages, if any, of one method or the other to define a control sequence to use in mathematics input?

Comment: The main difference is that you can use `\let\plus=+` in textmode as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there is performance: `\Umathchardef` will be slightly faster (there is less indirection after all), but that shouldn't be relevant in most cases.

On the other hand, setting the `\Umathcode` for `+` first and then using `\let` to define your symbol also sets the right `\Umathcode` for `+`, so you can also use `+` directly. Of course, even if you use `\Umathchardef` you can still assign the `\Umathcode`, but then they are not connected: If someone changes the `\Umathcode` for `+`, the command `\plus` defined as `\let\plus=+` changes too, but `\Umathchardef` has to be changed separately.
This is especially important in e.g. `unicode-math` which changes mathcodes a lot.

Also, they behave differently outside of math mode: For XeTeX, a command defined by `\Umathchardef` always yields an error outside of math mode. (In LuaTeX, it will insert the corresponding character from the text font.) While the `\let` based command always inserts the character the command was `\let` to in text mode. What is better again depends on the character: For `\sum`, there is no point in allowing it outside of math mode, so it should create an error there. On the other hand for `\alpha`, you might want the name to also allow inserting the greek character in text mode. In that case you could for example do

```
\Umathcode"03B1=2 0 "1D6FC
\let\alpha=α
```

then your math `\alpha` is italic math alpha , while your text mode `\alpha` is still a regular text α.

So `\Umathchardef` is a bit faster, has better error handling in XeTeX and doesn't introduce hidden dependencies on the mathcode of some character, but `\Umathcode` and `\let` are more flexible and might be shorter if you set the `\Umathcode` anyway.

Answer (score 4):

hyperref won't like it if you `\let` a command to a char. It is tricky to detect such commands and the hyperref code currently can't do it (this will perhaps change but not directly). There are a number of bug reports at the hyperref and unicode-math github about this, e.g. https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/63 and https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/532. Instead of using `\let`  it is better to use `\def` (`\newcommand`).

In the bookmarks you will see differences too. The `\Umathchardef` variant is currently lost (this will perhaps change too but also not directly).

```
\documentclass{article}

\Umathchardef\plusmathchar = 2 0 "002B

\Umathcode "002B = 2 0 "002B
\let\pluslet=+

\Umathcode "002B = 2 0 "002B
\newcommand\plusdef{+}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
$a$ % initialize math fonts

text: M \plusmathchar\ L \pluslet\ D  \plusdef  %error with xelatex

math: $ M \plusmathchar L \pluslet D \plusdef  $


\tableofcontents
\section{mathchar text X \plusmathchar\ Y} % error with xelatex
\section{mathchar math X $\plusmathchar$ Y}

%\section{let text X \pluslet\ Y} %lots of errors with hyperref
%\section{let math X $\pluslet$ Y}%lots of errors with hyperref 

\section{def text X \plusdef\ Y}
\section{def math X $\plusdef$ Y}

\end{document}
```

### output with lualatex

#### Compiled without hyperref and with the commented part:

[image]

#### Bookmarks:

[image]

Comment: The upcoming `text` module does handle all implicit chars properly, so we should be fine to handle this in `hyperref` (or ...)

Comment: @JosephWright I did write "this will perhaps change" for a reason ;-).

Answer (score 3):

We can check the difference of these two assignments in the log:

```
\Umathchardef\plus = 2 0 "002B
\show\plus

\Umathcode "002B = 2 0 "002B
\let\plus=+
\show\plus
\bye
```

```
> \plus=\Umathchar"2"00"00002B.
l.2 \show\plus

? 
> \plus=the character +.
l.6 \show\plus

?
```

The fundamental difference is that with `\Umathchardef\plus` you get a token that represents this particular math symbol *in the output*, whereas with `\let\plus=+` you make an alias for the `+` character *in the input*.

Another problem with the second variant is that it is non-local, i.e. the assignment of the mathcode and the definition of the control sequence do not take place in the same statement.

Also, the first statement is how it is meant to be done™.  From the TeXbook:

```
A~hundred or so definitions like
\begintt
\def\sum{\mathchar"1350 }
\endtt
would therefore suffice to define the special symbols of plain \TeX\null. But
there is a better way: \TeX\ has a primitive command ^|\mathchardef|,
which relates to |\mathchar| just as ^|\chardef| does to |\char|.
Appendix~B has a hundred or so definitions like
\begintt
\mathchardef\sum="1350
\endtt
to define the special symbols.
```

Comment: Bonus question about the TeXbook snippet: Why does Knuth use `\TeX\null.` instead of just `\TeX.`? If you want to answer, please do so in [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends).

Comment: The period should be considered as a sentence ending period. After `\null`, the space factor is set to 1000, so the period makes it 3000. Without the `\null`, the space factor would be 999 (because `\TeX` ends with `X`), so the period would not be considered as sentence ending. The LaTeX version of `\TeX` ends with `\@`.

Answer (score 1):

`unicode-math` uses the second approach for almost all symbols, as you can check (see Henri Menke's answer):

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

$\meaning\Bbbzero$, $\meaning\equiv$

\end{document}
```

[image]

So if you use Lua- or XeLaTeX the work is already done and you do not need to do it by hand. The best argument for this approach is that your code will be much more readable by avoiding many macros. Compare:

`$∫₀¹ x³ \, dx$` - `$\int_0^1 x^3 \, dx$`,
`$d²r²/d\vec r² = 2$` - `$d^2 r^2 / d\vec r^2 =2\Bbbone$`

As you try out the `\Umath...` commands I think that you consider unsing Plain Lua/XeTeX. In this case you have to do (or correct) it by hand as Lua- and XeTeX set the following `\Umathcode`s:

```
For letters: \Umathcode`<char> = 7 1 `<char>,
for numbers: \Umathcode`<char> = 7 0 `<char>,
else:        \Umathcode`<char> = 0 0 `<char>.
```

Then you have to write many lines for all the symbold you need. I did this some time ago as I like PlainTex. Here are some examples (my math font is in `\fam1`):

```
\Umathcode`∞="0"1`∞     \let\infty=∞
\Umathcode`="0"1`    \let\Bbbfour=
\Umathcode`∏="1"1`∏     \let\prod=∏
\Umathcode`∓="2"1`∓     \let\mp=∓
\Umathcode`↗="3"1`↗     \let\nearrow=↗
```